# Compiler error C2664 using std::map and custom class as its value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, stdmap, std-pair

I've done a lot of searching on this issue but none of the answers helped.

My setup

- Visual Studio 2017
- Windows 10

I have a large codebase, where in one class Bar

```cpp
// Bar.h

class Bar {
public:
   Bar();
   ~Bar();

public:
    ... // a long list of other methods.

private:
    std::map<std::string, Foo> m_foos;

};
```

then in its implementation

```
// Bar.cpp

Bar::Bar() {
   m_foos.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("id"), Foo()));              // Error 1
   m_foos.insert({std::string("id"), Foo()});                            // Error 2
   m_foos.insert(std::pair<std::string, Foo>(std::string("id"), Foo())); // Error 3
}
```

Trying to compile the above code gives me:

Error 1

```cpp
error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,Foo,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>,const std::pair<const _Kty,Foo> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,Foo>' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'
```

Error 2

```cpp
error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,Foo,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>,const std::pair<const _Kty,Foo> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'
```

Error 3

```cpp
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,Foo>'
```

However, with the same setup and compiler, the following much-simplified code compiles successfully:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { mi = 1; }
    ~Foo() {}

private:
    int mi;
};

class MyFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MyFoo() :Foo() {
        mj = 2;
        mk = nullptr;
    }
    ~MyFoo() {}

private:
    int mj;
    int* mk;
};

class YourFoo : public Foo {
public:
    YourFoo() :Foo() { mj = 2; }
    ~YourFoo() {}

private:
    int mj;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, Foo> yourmap;
    yourmap.insert(std::make_pair(3, Foo()));
    yourmap.insert({ 4, Foo() });
    yourmap.insert(std::pair<int, Foo>(5, Foo()));

}
```

Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

So I can finally reproduce it. It's due to the fact that the offending class hierarchy removed their copy constructors and `operator =`.

The modified example can reproduce the errors.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { mi = 1; }
    ~Foo() {}

    // NO COPIES.   
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo& operator = (const Foo &) = delete;

private:
    int mi;
};

class MyFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MyFoo() :Foo() {
        mj = 2;
        mk = nullptr;
    }
    ~MyFoo() {}

    // NO COPIES.
    MyFoo(const MyFoo &) = delete;
    MyFoo& operator = (const MyFoo &) = delete;

private:
    int mj;
    int* mk;
};

class YourFoo : public Foo {
public:
    YourFoo() :Foo() { mj = 2; }
    ~YourFoo() {}

    // NO COPIES.
    YourFoo(const YourFoo &) = delete;
    YourFoo& operator = (const YourFoo &) = delete;

private:
    int mj;
};


int main()
{
    std::map<int, Foo> yourmap;
    yourmap.insert(std::make_pair(3, Foo()));
    yourmap.insert({ 4, Foo() });
    yourmap.insert(std::pair<int, Foo>(5, Foo()));

}
```

So I guess the problem is that `std::map` must copy elements into its memory space. Then it just bumps into classes without copy constructors and complains. But the error messages are so misleading that I just can't figure out. The actual class hierarchy is pretty huge, so I didn't see those deleted parts. Guess someone does not want these things duplicated.

If anybody can instruct how to decipher the compiler error messages near the beginning of my question so that I may get a better idea where to look, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the role of `MyFoo` and `YourFoo` in the 2nd example?

Comment: What compiler do you use? It works on my Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: compile same code successfully in VS2017 on windows 10

Comment: @Scheff So you mean the errors may well be bogus .. I've seen many bogus error messages, but this one really got me. Indeed, I must incrementally change things until I find the difference between the code bases.

Comment: @PiotrSiekański It's the VS2017 one. Funny thing is the second example works with the same compiler.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the suggestions. Are there possible directions? I tried removing pointer members from the class, and change constructor signatures, ect. None made a difference. The fact that all three forms of insertion fail makes me think it's probably not the insertion code but the thing I'm trying to insert .. do you think so?

Comment: Please post a [mre], the code you have posted compiles for me: https://godbolt.org/z/p1XtGh

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry, I just updated my question with the reproducible case. I was struggling reproducing the errors with minimal example myself up until 1 min ago.

Comment: Your new example doesn't compile at all as `MyFoo` has both a default constructor and a deleted default constructor

Comment: @AlanBirtles My bad. Updated and should reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of classes without a usable copy constructor / copy assignment can still be used in `std::map` using a little special trick:

- emplace instead of insert (to construct the map entry in place)
- using `std::piecewise_construct`.

More about this on cppreference.com: [std::map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

Applied to OPs sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(): mi("1") { }
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;

private:
    std::string mi;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Foo &foo)
{
  return out << "Foo()";
}

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, Foo> yourmap;
#if 0 // WON'T COMPILE due to deleted Foo::Foo(const Foo&):
  yourmap.insert(std::make_pair("3", Foo()));
  yourmap.insert({ "4", Foo() });
  yourmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, Foo>("5", Foo()));
#endif // 0
  yourmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple("3"), // std::string("3")
    std::forward_as_tuple()); // Foo()
  // check result
  for (auto &entry : yourmap) {
    std::cout << '"' << entry.first << "\": " << entry.second << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
"3": Foo()
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a44b7fd36ca36b64)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { mi = 1; }
    ~Foo() {}

    // NO COPIES.   
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo& operator = (const Foo &) = delete;

private:
    int mi;
};

class MyFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MyFoo() :Foo() {
        mj = 2;
        mk = nullptr;
    }
    ~MyFoo() {}

    // NO COPIES.
    MyFoo(const MyFoo &) = delete;
    MyFoo& operator = (const MyFoo &) = delete;

private:
    int mj;
    int* mk;
};

class YourFoo : public Foo {
public:
    YourFoo() :Foo() { mj = 2; }
    ~YourFoo() {}

    // NO COPIES.
    YourFoo(const YourFoo &) = delete;
    YourFoo& operator = (const YourFoo &) = delete;

private:
    int mj;
};


int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Foo> > objects;
    objects.insert(std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<Foo> >(0, new Foo()));

}
```

Comment: Ok. So without modifying the constructor schemes,  the only way is to use dynamic allocation through shared pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I build this program on Visual Studio Community 2017 without any problem:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Foo {
public:
   Foo();
};

Foo::Foo() {
   std::cout << "Foo is being constructed\n";
}

class Bar {
public:
   Bar();
   ~Bar();

private:
   std::map<std::string, Foo> m_foos;

};

Bar::Bar() {
   m_foos.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("id"), Foo()));              
   m_foos.insert({ std::string("id"), Foo() });                            
   m_foos.insert(std::pair<std::string, Foo>(std::string("id"), Foo())); 
}

Bar::~Bar() {
   std::cout << "Destructing bar\n";
}

int main()
{
   Bar bar = Bar();
   std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Program output on console:

```
C:\Users\me\source\repos\SO0\Debug>SO0.exe
Foo is being constructed
Foo is being constructed
Foo is being constructed
Hello World!
Destructing bar
```